# Domain email, GMail, Postfix

Tags: gmail, ssl, forwarding, postfix

So, after a long trek around the blog-o-tubes, I arrive here.

I'm trying to set up email for my domain. I don't really want to do my own email hosting with my own mailserver, especially since my teeny tiny VPS instance is probably straining under the weight of running a webserver+app server+DB+the various message passing frameworks (hosting a prototype webapp)

I want to use my GMail address to send and receive email using my VPS as a relay - I set up email forwarding already using Postfix, so if someone sends something to "bobbytables@domain.com" it lands in my GMail account. Yay!

But now I want to respond from my GMail account, and have it forwarded to the recipient, with my domain specific email showing in the From: field. It'd be nice if everything could be done over SSL/TLS as well, for forwarding from my server to GMail, as well as requiring (or strongly preferring) it for incoming send/receive email connections. But I'm a bit lost in the master.cf/main.cf/iptables.rules files at the moment.

I just tried to close port 25 and open port 587 in iptables.rules (I understand 465 is now deprecated for SMTPS?), just to see what would happen, and incoming emails were just rejected according to the syslog - Google was trying to connect to port 25 still. But I guess I have to actually tell postfix to prefer SMTPS on 587? Is that the "smtps inet ...." line or the "submission inet..." line that I have to uncomment? And I understand that I can point my gmail account at an SMTP server, but then how do I actually create users for postfix? Do I actually create user accounts with useradd (bad, more attack "surface"), or can I create "virtual" accounts just for postfix to send mail with? In both cases, SSL/TLS seems kind of mandatory at least for the auth step...

So far I created some self-signed certs and told Postfix where they are, but now I'm kinda stuck: what ports do I open, what...err...things do I point at other things...how do I tell incoming connections "yo, encrypt yo'self homeboy"?

I've struggled with this for quite a while, and had a look through quite a few guides, but most were geared towards setting up a full mail stack, which I don't really want to do (out of resource-scarcity rather than laziness :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Follow this [Ubuntu Postfix Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) to configure postfix, pay attention for sasl setup. That is for postfix authentication. Submission port will be 587.
2. Create Linux user(eg `bobbytables`) for email address `bobbytables@domain.com`.

   ```
   sudo adduser bobbytables
   ```
3. SASL Check List

   Go through the SASL check list in [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/475064/138643) to make sure sasl configuration is complete.

Comment: Is there a way to have email addresses without having corresponding system accounts? Like, virtual users? A few guides imply this, but then it seems to require using an actual mailserver like Courier.

Comment: Courier is not required. However in this case using actual linux user is the easiest way. Setting up mysql tables with virtual domain and users seems way overkill in this situation. You can also check out [my blog](http://johnsiu.com), the way I did it was even more lazier, lol.

Comment: So I created the bobbytables user, set a password and tried to "Add another email address you own" on GMail. It threw a Postfix 535 error when trying to connect on :465 using TLS. This led me to:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-linux-postfix-sasl-authentication-error/

which I gave a go, and still, 535. I know I'm not mistyping the password, so what am I missing?


@JohnSiu, basic forwarding already works for me, it's just responding with the domain email that's left to sort out :) The Ubuntu walkthrough was useful for securing the connections though, thanks!

Comment: Port 465 is for smtp ssl, or smtps. If you are connecting to that port, choose SSL in your client, not TLS. If you use want to use TLS, choose port 587.

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf`?

Comment: I tried:

[TLS+465] - couldn't reach server;   
[TLS+587] - couldn't reach server;  
[SSL+465] - couldn't reach server;  
[SSL+587] - couldn't reach server;  
[SSL+25] - couldn't reach server;  
[TLS+25] - Authentication failed. Please check your username/password. 
[Server response: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure code(535) ];  

And...hello, I don't have a file /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf. Might be relevant...

Comment: You need that file or postfix cannot connect sasl at all. It is the #1 item in the check list.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot to hg push after I added that file. Doh! 587 on TLS works now :). Thanks John!